Missing calculation of disk partition in ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
I have assigned 11T of multiple virtual disks to a virtual machine but in the OS level it is showing only 10T to a mountpoint and there is 0 free in the volume group.
XFS
df -h
Total=11T
Used=9.5T
Available=586G
% = 95%
df 1-k block
Total=10799470596
Used=10187095768
Available=612374828
% = 95%
where is my 900G I am confused someone please help me

If your system still reports itself as running 20.04.2, you're very behind on applying all fixes & I'd be checking that. This post (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/) shows the ISO release date of 20.04.3, but installed systems upgraded before the ISO release date, so check you've been applying security fixes & other updates since then, as your details imply you've not (and may have other problems & not just related to disk)
